# Models have to be imported twice

Tags: python, import, module

I have a tkinter program and my directory looks such,

Folder:
 main.py : to create the main window where all would be controlled
 Data folder:
   New_Window.py : has a function `add_label` to add label to the window passed as argument

[image: Code Screenshots]

The problem is in the New_Window.py (on the right in image) I again have to 'import all from tkinter' for the system to work when I run the main.py(on the left in image) file.
If I don't specify it in the New_Window file and run the main.py, it gives me an error saying "Label not define".

But I already have tkinter import in main file, so do I still need to import all in the New_Window file or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes, you need to `import` on the other file too. But you should probably just include what you need. So in `New_Window.py` you could do just `from tkinter import Label`.

Comment: That's exactly how python is designed to work. Each file needs to import the modules that it uses.

Comment: Ohkay, thank you all!

Comment: Could you also tell if the 'import' statement should at the top OR under 'if __name__ == "__main__"'?